# Autofill textboxes in dnn "Dynamic Form Module" on drop down selected value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dotnetnuke-5

**I have a problem in DNN Module i.e "Dynamic Form Module" in which i want to auto fill the text boxes on the drop down selected value.but i am not able to find any solution regarding this please help me thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do this client side with javascript?
Write some jQuery to populate your drop down menu? Or monitor it's change and change the values?